# Projections of trees in transitive models of set theory

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I'm going through some problems about absoluteness for transitive models and got stuck on something:

Let $M$ be a transitive model of ZFC. Let $T$ be a tree on $\omega\times\omega$ with $T\in M$, and let $x\in M$ be such that $x\in \text{proj}([T])$, i.e.
$$
\exists y\in \omega^\omega \forall n<\omega [(x|n,y|n)\in T].
$$
Does it necessarily follow that $(x\in \text{proj}([T]))^M$? Since the property of being a function $\omega\to\omega$ is absolute, $(\omega^\omega)^M=\omega^\omega\cap M$, so that $(x\in\text{proj}([T]))^M$ would mean that
$$
\exists y\in\omega^\omega\cap M\forall n<\omega [(x|n,y|n)\in T]
$$
by absoluteness of the various notions involved. So I'd need to construct an element of $M\cap\omega^\omega$ which satisfies the above formula, but I don't see how to do this.

Comment: That $x\in{\rm proj}([T])$ means that a certain tree (that depends on $T$ and $x$) is ill-founded (namely, the tree of attempts to build a witness $y$). It is easy to see that the this tree $T_x$ is sufficiently absolute so that $T_x\in M$ and $(T_x)^M=T_x$. The question for you is then whether well-foundedness of trees reflects between $V$ and $M$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Oh, I hadn't thought about phrasing it in terms of ill-foundedness of the tree $T_x$, I'll meditate on the details now. Thank you very much!

Comment: What you were given to prove is called $\mathbf\Sigma^1_1$ absolutness. An extension of this is Schoenfield absoluteness which gives the absolutness of $\mathbf\Sigma^1_2$ formulas.